# How to distinguish Navigation Properties from regular ones when using GetProperties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

Is there a way to distinguish between a regular collection property and a navigation property on an Entity-Framework class (Database-First)?

I'm currently checking if the object `is ICollection` and `IsVirtual` but I feel this could possibly trigger on a regular property that someone has declared as a virtual collection.

**Question:** Are there any other ways to distinguish Navigation Properties from others?

**Context**: I'm using this to compare values of any object, but I want it to ignore navigation properties (to ignore circular-references among other things).

```
foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)obj)
{
    list2.MoveNext();
    var item2 = list2.Current;
    foreach (PropertyInfo propInfo in item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        Object v1 = propInfo.GetValue(item);
        Object v2 = propInfo.GetValue(item2);

        Primitive = (v1 == null && v2 == null) || IsPrimitive(v1.GetType());

        if (Primitive)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(v1, v2);
        }
        else
        {
            // Ignore Navigation Properties
            // Currently assuming Virtual properties to be Navigation...
            if (propInfo.GetGetMethod().IsVirtual) continue;
            CompareObjects(v1, v2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `"" is ICollection`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say?

Comment: Your check will fail for virtual string properties.

Comment: oh, wasn't aware of that. Just another reason I need to know more about Navigation Properties so I can better distinguish them from regular ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you want to know the names of the navigation properties and the scalar properties related to an Entity, I suggest you use this code:

```
using (var db = new YourContext())
{
    var workspace = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    var itemCollection = (ObjectItemCollection)(workspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace));
    var entityType = itemCollection.OfType<EntityType>().Single(e => itemCollection.GetClrType(e) == typeof(YourEntity));
    
    foreach (var navigationProperty in entityType.NavigationProperties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(navigationProperty.Name);
    }
    
    foreach (var property in entityType.Properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(property.Name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution when using GetProperties() is to create an IEntity interface and apply it to all entities. Then you can skip over single entity navigation properties by checking if they implement IEntity and multiple entity navigation 
if they are of type ICollection.

So in your foreach,

```
if (property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<>)) continue;
if (property.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEntity))) continue;
```

Here is a simple method to return only updateable properties using this logic:

```
private IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetUpdateableProperties<T>(T entity) where T : IEntity
    {
        return entity.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty)
            .Where(property =>
                property.CanWrite &&
                !property.PropertyType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IEntity)) &&
                !(property.PropertyType.IsGenericType && property.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
                );
    }
```

Comment: This would work in a sort but what if you have a class that had an `ICollection` that wasn't a navigation property. Personally can't imagine a scenario, but still something to consider. Also what about single object navigation properties?

Comment: I modified my answer to deal with single object navigation.  I don't see how an entity property of entity framework could be a ICollection accept for navigation properties so I don't bother with that.  But you could check that the ICollection is of IEntity.