# Automapper : Ignore Navigation Properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, automapper

I've read the 2 proposed answers here and these 2 answers do not match what I want to do as they are manual work. So If I add another navigation property, I would need to modify AutoMapper config.

The main goal is to make EF objects serializable, without removing lazy loading.

I'm looking to write something like that :

```
cfg.CreateMap<EntityA, EntityA>(new IgnoreNavigationsProperties());
```

I'm not looking to identify each property one by one. It should use reflecion. (I can manage reflection part, just need some help to get started to how I could do that code.).

Any help or direction is welcome !

Edit :

So I start to get somewhere with converters.

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
public class EfEntityConverter<T> : ITypeConverter<T, T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <param name="destination"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <exception cref="NotImplementedException"></exception>
    public T Convert(T source, T destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        
    }
}
```

But I get a lot of warnings (Which I treat as errors. And If I implement that converter, that will be horrible performances as Convert will be executed each time and I would run reflexion on each object.

So, any idea how to make it better ? (Sometiomes, I need to run it on 100.000+ objects)

Comment: Anyway, it seems like you might need [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28413410/3181933) as a basis for determining navigation properties vs normal properties.

Comment: I can. But it's bit long : "Norma;" propertu like "int" is directlly linked to a database column. A complex reference like "EntityA.EntityB based on a foregin key" is a navigation property. In a nutshell, with Lazy loading, when you wrtite entityA.EntityB, that will generate an SQL querry to get EntityB. But, entityB can have other navigation properties. So when you try to serialize it, well, serializer will try to parse them all, which can lead to more than 1000 SQL request to serialize an object. Lazy loading is great for dev. Not grea when you serialize.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar thanks you, but that won't work. As that check takes more than 1 second on our DbContext. I'm looking for a way to make a static, precompiled map. Before actual mapping takes place. Thanks for your time !

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking it might be a bit slow. I do wonder if you couldn't use it as the basis of building some kind of lookup object at startup.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar that's what I want to do, I simplified example to 1 object, but I want to build a full DI system which will automaticlly provide mapping to all EF objects, stripiong all navigation properties and detach from EF core context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection can't tell you everything about EF Core's data model. Instead you can build a hashset of all your navigation properties from your `DbContext.Model`;

```cs
using var scope = provider.CreateScope();

var db = scope.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();
var model = db.Model;
var entities = model.GetEntityTypes();

var navigationProperties = entities
    .SelectMany(e => e.GetNavigations())
    // ignore owned type navigations, treat them as part of the data;
    .Where(n => !n.ForeignKey.IsOwnership && n.PropertyInfo!=null)
    .Select(n => n.PropertyInfo)
    .Concat(
        entities
            .SelectMany(e => e.GetSkipNavigations())
            .Where(n => n.PropertyInfo!=null)
            .Select(n => n.PropertyInfo)
    )
    .ToHashSet();
```

You'll want to store this hashset somewhere as a singleton, so you only build it once, or perhaps once per entity type.

From there you probably want to dynamically build an expression tree equivalent to `t => new T{ A = t.A, .... };`, skipping any navigation properties from your model.

```cs
var parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "t");

var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T,T>>(
    Expression.MemberInit(
        Expression.New(typeof(T)),
        typeof(T)
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite)
            .Except(navigationProperties)
            .Select(p => Expression.Bind(p, Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parm, p)))
    ),
    parm
);

var factoryMethod = expr.Compile();
```

Now you can call this method from your `.Convert()` method to create the copy of the object.

Though this trivial implementation will only make a shallow copy of each property. For some property types, such as owned types, a deep copy would be needed.

Comment: Thank you. I actully want to avoid deep copy (there are plenty of libs for that). I woud need some time to test. It seems (Maybe I'm wrong .GetProperties() will be called on each convert. That may be slow. I will be testing that tomorrow.

Comment: No, the idea is to call all the above code once per type, leaving only the compiled factory method.